# How to make Axios requests work on mobile in React.js

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

After deploying my live site, everything works on desktop. I am able to take user input, send it to the server, and then send it to my email using [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/).

But, for some reason it doesn't work on my phone or any other phone.

I have tried doing a simple get request and that doesn't work either. I have tried using fetch. I know the function still works on mobile because I tested other functionality with no problem, it is just the HTTP request that is not working.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
        const { name, email, phone } = this.state
        e.preventDefault()

        const userInfo= {
            name, email, phone
        }
        const newInfo= JSON.stringify(userInfo)
        axios.post("http://localhost:9000/email", newInfo).then(res => console.log(res.data));
}
```

My form looks like this

```
<form name="contact" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
     <input type="text" name="phone" value={phone} onChange={this.handleChange} />
     <input type="text" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} />  
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

I've tried events on the button like `onClick` and `onStartTouch` for phones and mobile and still no result. Do HTTP requests work different with phones and mobile devices?

Comment: Why are you using a static port (9000)?

Comment: Have You Fixed The Issue I Am Facing The Same Issue Now

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same issue, web desktop works fine, but when access in mobile device, get the "NetworkError"

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: use the ip andress of the machine just like 192.168.10.22:8001

Comment: I have SSL configured and the backend can be accessed with HTTPS and it corresponds to its domain. So Is it valid to use server IP address instead of a domain name like for e.g. https://domain-name.com:8001

Answer (score 0):

If your backend address is `localhost:5000`, you could change domain to ip address. Example `http://192.168.1.82:5000`

Answer (score 0):

i did a proxy config in vite and react but with the localhost to 192.168.1.82 works well.